# How to let CGI input field return to its initial state when a condition is fulfilled (CGI.pm/Perl)

Tags: html, perl, web, cgi

I have a CGI script that looks like this.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use CGI ':standard';

print header;
print start_html('A Simple Example'),
h1('A Simple Example'),
start_form,
"What's your name? ",textfield('name'),
p, submit, end_form,
hr;

my %unwantedwords = {'foo' => 1 };

if (param())
{
    my $text =param('name');

    # I attempted this to but failed.
    unless ($unwantedwords{$text}){
        print  "Your name is: ",$text,
   }
    hr;
}
print
end_html;
```

What I want to do is basically to receive a text via 'textfield' and then print it out on the web.  But when a word inserted by user is an unwanted words (stored in  the hash),
instead of printing it I'd like the web to return to it's fresh initial state.

What's the best way to do it?
The above code doesn't work.

Comment: Use an @array to store your not wanted keywords and grep to filter them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like, (Untested)..

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw( :standard );
use CGI::Carp qw( fatalsToBrowser );

my @unwanted = qw( foo bar baz );

my $text = param('name');

print header,
      start_html('A Simple Example');

display_form() and exit unless !grep($text eq $_, @unwanted);

print "Hello $text\n";

sub display_form {
   print start_form,
         h1('A Simple Example'),
         qq( What's your name? ), textfield(-name => 'name', -value => '', -override => 1), p,
         submit, hr,
         end_form;
}

print end_html;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works pretty well. But although the unwanted words didn't get printed out, it still persist in the text field display over the web. How can I clear the content of this text field?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to save the state of the word before it is submitted, and retrieve it to send back if the submitted word is on your list of bad words.

Your implementation will differ depending on your persistence engine, but regardless of whether you use a cookie to store the old word, or use a session store, you'll do something like this:

```
 1. store the old word

 2. send the old word along with the web form.

 3. receive new word back

 4. if (new word is in the bad word list) {
      get the old word from storage
    }
    else {
      store the new word
    }

 5. do what comes next
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do you implement no.2 and 3?

Comment: 2) The code that generates the form, sets it as the value attribute of the apropriate text field

Comment: 3) you've already implemented (3) in the code that you posted above.